# Hadoop MapReduce reading data from multiple blocks simultaneously

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have  employees data in 4 files .

Q1.txt

```
11 23 13
34 45 21
15 18 27
```

Q2.txt

```
08 17 14
10 26 29
30 03 10
```

Q3.txt

```
45 67 29
56 67 89
98 87 65
```

Q4.txt

```
23 78 45
43 32 11
91 56 99
```

I need to calculate each employee min,max,total,average 
example:-

```
11+23+13+08+17+14+45+67+29+23+78+45 => 

min =  11,max=78,total=783,Average=65.25
```

Like these I have to calculate all the employees details by using MapReduce.

Please help me how many mappers and reducers are required along with logic.

Comment: What have you tried and what specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: i tried to read by using  offset and break but i found that is not useful approach .Please suggest if you have any

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you're reading this data, so it's hard to help you, and Stackoverflow isn't a coding service, so please add your code for where you're stuck. Also, you might want to look at this class https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html

Comment: Thanks Cricket_007 for your message. If I know the solution I could have tried it. What you shared is multi inputs. So you didn't get my question where it is reading data multiple blocks at a time.